# Importing Excel files to access with macro

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to import a couple hundred excel files into one access table. I found this code online but it doesn't seem to be working. I put this is in a new Module, click run, and nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

```
Function DoImport()

   Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
   Dim strTable As String
   Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

   ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
   ' has field names
   blnHasFieldNames = True

   ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
   ' contains the EXCEL files
   strPath = "C:\Test\TEST\"

   ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
   ' the data are to be imported
   strTable = "Table1"

   strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
   Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile
       DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
              strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

     ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
     ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
     '       Kill strPathFile

     strFile = Dir()
   Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Is it actually finding any of the files?

Comment: It is finding the files and loading them but its throwing "Type Conversion error" because some of the cells are blank in the original sheet but there are to many sheets to go in an change them manually.

Comment: You can try creating a different table to import the files to (one with more-generic field types?), then use SQL to reformat the imported data and copy it to the final table.

Comment: What type of generic table rows would you recommend for a table that is going to contain blanks?

Comment: Text seems like a safe bet, and allow nulls.

Comment: It still throws the same error. Is there anyway I can make a whole column formatted as text?

Comment: [Cause & (possible) solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109376)

Comment: I think you'd need to provide more detail about the actual problem.  It's not clear what it is about the blank cells which is causing the import to fail.

Comment: Why don't you import 1 sheet using access import/Export and save the importExport. run your loop > edit the savedImport xml, re-run the import > do this until no files found?

Answer (score 0):

The spreadsheets must all have the same columns and data types as the destination table when using TransferSpreadheet.

You can set all fields in the table to Text and that will allow you to import the spreadsheets regardless of the data types but you may get import errors if the columns don't match the table.

Even after you import the data as Text you'll have to use some combination of SQL and UDF to test and convert the data back to the desired data type.

Here is a the UDF I use to test data types and conver it to whatever I need:

```
Public Function ValidateField(FieldVal As Variant, dbFieldID As Variant) As Variant
    If IsError(FieldVal) Then
        Select Case dbFieldID
            Case dbText
                ValidateField = Null
            Case dbInteger
                ValidateField = 0
            Case dbLong
                ValidateField = 0
            Case dbDouble
                ValidateField = 0
            Case dbDate
                ValidateField = 0
            Case dbCurrency
                ValidateField = 0
            Case Else
                ValidateField = Null
        End Select
    Else
        Select Case dbFieldID
            Case dbText
                ValidateField = CStr(FieldVal)
            Case dbInteger
                ValidateField = CInt(FieldVal)
            Case dbLong
                ValidateField = CLng(FieldVal)
            Case dbDouble
                ValidateField = CDbl(FieldVal)
            Case dbDate
                ValidateField = CDate(FieldVal)
            Case dbCurrency
                ValidateField = CCur(FieldVal)
            Case Else
                ValidateField = CVar(FieldVal)
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```